# How to configure process exporter to prometheus config file?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-process-exporter

> I am trying to implement prometheus process exporter from this link [Process exporter](https://github.com/ncabatoff/process-exporter) and need guidance how to add process exporter in prometheus yml file. 
>   If somebody help me in which port process exporter is running so that it helps to add the port in prometheus yml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Download and extract your node exporter and run using the below command,

```
./process-exporter --config.path=process.yml --web.listen-address=localhost:6789
```

> note: 6789 will be any port address you need to run
>
> Same in prometheus config file add the port address you are running for your process exporter

Answer (score 0):

By default 9256 will be your port on which you can capture metrics.